# Some images cannot be uploaded into codeigniter site

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, file-upload, frameworks

I am developing a website for my university project. I have to upload some images to the site. SO I used below mentioned code. Few images cannot be uploaded to the website. I don't know the reason. Please help me. Thank you

function upload_file($filename){

```
    $config['file_name']     = time().$_FILES[$filename]['name']; // append time to filename
    $config['upload_path']   = './assets/images/adsimages';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png|GIF|JPG|PNG|JPEG';
    $config['max_size'] = '2048000';


    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->initialize($config);

    $uploaded = $this->upload->do_upload($filename);

    if ( ! $uploaded ){

        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $file  = 'no_image.jpg'; // default file

    }else{

        $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
        $file        = $upload_data['file_name']; // uploaded file name
    }

    return $file; // return filename
}
```

Comment: would help to describe size, file extension, filename of what is not working, as well as any error  messages

Comment: it can be the file size or allowed types ? show the display errors

Comment: one hint: it could be a .jpeg file saved by windows10 in jfif format, the jfif mime type is not listed in config/mimes.php, add this line `'jfif' => 'image/jpeg', `

Comment: image which can't be uploaded is JPG File (.jpg) , size = 479 KB , dimension 713x1248

Comment: explore and see if it is jfif

Comment: It shows as jpg file. But I don't know how to check if the exact file type was hidden.

Comment: I changed the code to             $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png|GIF|JPG|PNG|JPEG|jfif';      still that image couldn't upload

Comment: because jfif is not part of the file config/mime.php, the easiest is adding the line I mentioned in above comment directly there, or like this: https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/config.html#setting-a-config-item

Comment: I am not a expert of coding . Could you please explain where to use that code in my coding.

Comment: Just open in your CI project, application/config/mimes.php and add this array entry `'jfif' => 'image/jpeg',` it might work, at least W3org says that's the correct mime type for jfif: https://www.w3.org/Graphics/JPEG/

Comment: Your support is highly appriciated. I add that code as you described and test  jfif image files can be uploaded. But the image which I was described earlier cannot be uploaded yet

Comment: last try: `'jfif'  =>  array('image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg'),`

Comment: I didn't work. Thanks for your help

Comment: Steve, could you please upload that image in question to a server so I can download and test it? I have experienced a similar case and I'm interested in digging a bit deeper into it, thanks